# Quadratic Bezier curves representation as implicit quadratic equation

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry

A quadratic bezier curve from points `P1=(x1, y1)` to `P3=(x3, y3)` with control point `P2=(x2, y2)` can be represented as parametric quadratic curve `P(t)` where `t` is in `[0, 1]`.

$$P(t) = (P_1t + P_2(1 - t))t + (P_2t + P_3(1 - t))(1 - t)
         = P_1t^2 + P_2(1 - t)t + P_3(1 - t)^2$$

We can extend the range of t to be all real numbers, from minus infinity to plus infinity, and then we will get a nice curve dividing the plane in two.

I read somewhere, that this infinete curve is either a straight line (if `P1`, `P2` and `P3` are colinear) or a parabola. Could you please confirm that?

Since division of plane by a parabola or a line can be expressed by quadratic equation of form:

```
Point P=(x, y) is 
  on one side  if F(P) > 0
  on the other if F(P) < 0
  on the curve if F(P) == 0
where F(P) = A * x^2 + B * y^2 + C * x * y + D * x + E * y + F
```

How can we, starting from points `P1, P2, P3` calculate the numbers `A, B, C,D, E, F`?

I think something similar is done in this wolfram demostration http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/FocusAndDirectrixInAQuadraticBezierCurve/

Thank you

Comment: You have an infinite supply of points satisfying $F(P) = 0$. What can you get with that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kindly [ask Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Collect%5BExpand%5BEliminate%5B%7Bx1*t%5E2%2bx2*t*%281-t%29*2%2bx3*%281-t%29%5E2==x,y1*t%5E2%2by2*t*%281-t%29*2%2by3*%281-t%29%5E2==y%7D,t%5D%5D,%7Bx,y%7D%5D) to

```
Collect[Expand[Eliminate[{
  x1*t^2 + x2*t*(1-t)*2 + x3*(1-t)^2 == x,
  y1*t^2 + y2*t*(1-t)*2 + y3*(1-t)^2 == y
}, t]], {x, y}]
```

and it will tell you

[image: Result]

which you can reformulate to something close to

\begin{align*}F(x, y) =&\phantom{+}
x^2 (y_1^2-4 y_1 y_2+2 y_1 y_3+4 y_2^2-4 y_2 y_3+y_3^2) \\
&+xy (-2 x_1 y_1+4 x_1 y_2-2 x_1 y_3+4 x_2 y_1-8 x_2 y_2+4 x_2 y_3-2 x_3 y_1+4 x_3 y_2-2 x_3 y_3) \\
&+x (2 x_1 y_1 y_3-4 x_1 y_2^2+4 x_1 y_2 y_3-2 x_1 y_3^2+4 x_2 y_1 y_2-8 x_2 y_1 y_3+4 x_2 y_2 y_3-2 x_3 y_1^2+4 x_3 y_1 y_2+2 x_3 y_1 y_3-4 x_3 y_2^2) \\
&- y^2 (-x_1^2+4 x_1 x_2-2 x_1 x_3-4 x_2^2+4 x_2 x_3-x_3^2) \\
&- y (2 x_1^2 y_3-4 x_1 x_2 y_2-4 x_1 x_2 y_3-2 x_1 x_3 y_1+8 x_1 x_3 y_2-2 x_1 x_3 y_3+4 x_2^2 y_1+4 x_2^2 y_3-4 x_2 x_3 y_1-4 x_2 x_3 y_2+2 x_3^2 y_1) \\
&+(x_1^2 y_3^2-4 x_1 x_2 y_2 y_3-2 x_1 x_3 y_1 y_3+4 x_1 x_3 y_2^2+4 x_2^2 y_1 y_3-4 x_2 x_3 y_1 y_2+x_3^2 y_1^2)
\end{align*}

So the parameters of your conic will be

\begin{align*}
A =&
y_1^{2} - 4 \, y_1 y_2 + 2 \, y_1 y_3 + 4 \, y_2^{2} - 4 \, y_2 y_3 +
y_3^{2}
\\
B =&
x_1^{2} - 4 \, x_1 x_2 + 2 \, x_1 x_3 + 4 \, x_2^{2} - 4 \, x_2 x_3 +
x_3^{2}
\\
C =&
-2 \, x_1 y_1 + 4 \, x_1 y_2 - 2 \, x_1 y_3 + 4 \, x_2 y_1 - 8 \, x_2
y_2 + 4 \, x_2 y_3 - 2 \, x_3 y_1 + 4 \, x_3 y_2 - 2 \, x_3 y_3
\\
D =&
2 \, x_1 y_1 y_3 - 4 \, x_1 y_2^{2} + 4 \, x_1 y_2 y_3 - 2 \, x_1
y_3^{2} + 4 \, x_2 y_1 y_2 - 8 \, x_2 y_1 y_3
\\ &+\, 4 \, x_2 y_2 y_3 - 2 \,
x_3 y_1^{2} + 4 \, x_3 y_1 y_2 + 2 \, x_3 y_1 y_3 - 4 \, x_3 y_2^{2}
\\
E =&
-2 \, x_1^{2} y_3 + 4 \, x_1 x_2 y_2 + 4 \, x_1 x_2 y_3 + 2 \, x_1 x_3
y_1 - 8 \, x_1 x_3 y_2 + 2 \, x_1 x_3 y_3
\\ &-\, 4 \, x_2^{2} y_1 - 4 \,
x_2^{2} y_3 + 4 \, x_2 x_3 y_1 + 4 \, x_2 x_3 y_2 - 2 \, x_3^{2} y_1
\\
F =&
x_1^{2} y_3^{2} - 4 \, x_1 x_2 y_2 y_3 - 2 \, x_1 x_3 y_1 y_3 + 4 \, x_1
x_3 y_2^{2} + 4 \, x_2^{2} y_1 y_3 - 4 \, x_2 x_3 y_1 y_2 + x_3^{2}
y_1^{2}
\end{align*}

The above was computed using [sage](http://sagemath.org/), where I could get the output into the form I needed more easily. This should agree with the first formula, but if it does not, this here is the more reliable one. You can check that $4AB-C^2=0$ which proves that this conic is indeed a parabola.

Comment: wow, thank you. will try it out.

Answer (score 3):

The point $(x,y)$ is on the quadratic Bezier curve if the equations
$$
  x1*t^2 + x2*t*(1-t)*2 + x3*(1-t)^2 = x \\
  y1*t^2 + y2*t*(1-t)*2 + y3*(1-t)^2 = y
$$
have a common solution, $t$. There is an extensive theory (mostly lost in the mists of time) that tells us when two polynomials have a common root. Look for references on elimination theory and resultants. Specific resultants bear the names of Dixon, Sylvester, and others. A fairly recent reference is [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~hulya/Publications/IJCV03Paper.pdf). Resultants are attractive because they show some structure -- the formulae look much nicer than the mass of symbols that you get by brute-force elimination using programs like Alpha or Sage.

Comment: If you move P3 to the origin, the vector equation is (P1-2 P2) t² + 2 P2 t = P, and changing coordinates to the frame formed by P1-2 P2 and 2P2,  you have X = t², Y = t !